# Findbugs dataflow analysis

Tags: analysis, findbugs, dataflow

I'm using Findbugs to find the definition of a variable. The use case is that if a detector finds a bug, I need know where the definition of the variable related to the bug. Is there any API or I need implement it.

Comment: i am not sure if i am correct, you should find some files like findbugs.xml, or bugs.xml or messages.xml